# Prefix url helpers in subdomain constraints without having the prefix in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

Here is my `routes.rb` file :

```
  constraints subdomain: 'pro' do
    scope module: 'pro' do
      resources :subjects
    end
  end
```

This will generate:

```
   subjects GET /subjects(.:format) pro/subjects#index {:subdomain=>"pro"}
```

How can I have the `pro_subject` url helper without having the '/pro' prefix in the URL as I already have the subdomain.

I want people to type: http://pro.mysuperwebsite.com and not http://pro.mysuperwebsite.com/pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if you set the `:path` option, you can determine the subpath.

```
namespace :pro, :path => '' do # This should do it
```